# If one item in JSON has multiple lines text, does it need indentation?

Tags: json

I have a JSON example file. I have a simple question but cannot find the answer. If one item in JSON has multiple lines text, does it need indentation? Please see the picture below, which one is correct?

```
"ff": "sadf asdf sdf
sadf asdf asdf asdf
asdfsadfs",
```

or

```
"ff": "sdfasd asdfsa
       asdfsadfasdfs
       asdf",
```

[image]

Comment: I think it needs a `\n`

Comment: @keltar: No, the literal line break is invalid.

Comment: @keltar: Interesting. That would be a non-compliant parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation is completely irrelevant in JSON. However, you can't have a literal line break inside a string, you have to use `\n`. According to [json.org](http://json.org/), a string is an opening double quote followed by any number of any Unicode character *except* control characters or unescaped `"` or `\` characters (`"` because it terminates the string, `\` because it's what introduces escape sequences). Line breaks are control characters.

Consequently, both of your example fragments are invalid. A valid fragment would be:

```
"ff": "sadf asdf sdf\nsadf asdf asdf asdf\nasdfsadfs",
```